# Puppet code to download extract and install

Tags: puppet

I have a file at some web URL (http://www.somewhere.com/something.tar.gz).
This is direct download link.
I need a puppet code that would download this file, extract it and install the file.

Can we do this using `package {}` in puppet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really an intrinsic provider for the package type that understands tarballs. There is, however, this VoxPopuli module: https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/archive which was recently Puppet certified and should do what you need.

Note under their usage example it could be modified for your needs like:

```
archive { '/tmp/something':
  ensure        => present,
  extract       => true,
  extract_path  => '/tmp',
  source        => 'http://www.somewhere.com/something.tar.gz',
  checksum      => 'checksum hash',
  checksum_type => 'sha1',
  creates       => '/tmp/something',
  cleanup       => true,
}
```

Comment: In init.pp I have to   `include ::archive`??

Comment: Yes, or declare the class instead. Your choice.